# Running Several Apps Within a WPF Host

Tags: wpf

I have several independent WPF apps that need to run in their own process (it is not adequate for them to run in separate app domains or contexts - it must be a separate process), but Ive been tasked with looking at ways to host them all in a single WPF 'frame' (whatever that might mean). The 'frame' would be responsible for opening, closing and moving each app within its own docking system.

Can anyone let me know the best approach to achieve something like this ? and maybe the potential pitfalls ?

Comment: Do you mean something like MDI?